# Shows the reader?

Tags: grammar

I am writing a thesis and I have the following sentence:
The section [...] shows the reader, that [...]

I am not sure about the "shows the reader"?

Should I use it or just "shows"?

Comment: Writing advice requests are off topic. If you have a specific concern or question about the phrase "shows the readers" please edit the question to explain what it is.

Comment: They do not mean the same. Decide according to what you like to convey.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here are a few different options.  You could say:

- This section explains (to the reader)
- This section demonstrates (to the reader)
- This section leads the reader to believe...

With the "to the reader" being optional in both cases, but only if it makes sense in context (obviously).

Comment: I feel that indicating 'the section' as agent is not wonderful style. I'd prefer 'In section 2, it is shown that ...' or 'In section 2, ... is explained / discussed / demonstrated.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, to treat a section as an agent is a common and simple metaphor.  To do so is not a style problem.   Writing a weak and wordy passive form when you can write an active sentence *is* a style problem.

Comment: Why did I get a down vote?